# Using node typescript with mongoose and elastic search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, elasticsearch, mongoose

i tried to build a full-text search with mongodb, but it doesn't work really well. While searching for a performant solution I came across elastic search. After a long search, I came across many different solutions but I'm not sure which is the best.
My idea is now to synchronize the data with elastic to on the node server with change streams.
During the search, elastic should give me a list of IDs with which I can then fetch the documents from mongodb and return them to the client. My question now is whether you can do this with node and mongodb or whether there are even better solutions here. It is important to me that I can control everything via the node server. In the future, I would also like to promote data, rank,... with the help of elastic search.

I appreciate your answers.

Comment: "elastic should give me a list of IDs with which I can then fetch the documents from mongodb" Why not fetch the documents from Elasticsearch itself?

Comment: Because I'm using models with nested objects and elastic search don't like nested objects (correct me if i'm wrong) and I only sync the fields which I need for the search to elastic.

Comment: what didn't work very well with MongoDB text search? Were you using Atlas Search?

Comment: @Nice-Guy I'm working the first time with mongodb. I tried to create a regular text index for the search but that was not really performant. I never heard from Atlas Search. Does it work different from a regular text index? Is Atlas Search like Elastic search?

Comment: @saibot it's like Elasticsearch.